# Decompose a relation to 2NF and preserve all the functional dependencies

Tags: normalization, relational-theory

For example, consider the following relation:

```
R(A, B, C, D, E)
```

With the functional dependencies (FDs) shown below:

```
{A→B,  BC→E,  D→C}
```

Here candidate key is `{AD}` and the relation is not in second normal form (2NF) because of the partial dependencies `A→B`,  `D→C`.

Now, if I decompose R as follows:

```
R1(AB) ,  R2(CD),  R3(ADE)
```

...these relations are now in 2NF, but the FD `BC→E` is lost.

How can I decompose R to comply with 2NF and preserve the FDs?

Answer (score 3):

One decomposition in 3NF (and so also in 2NF) is:

```
R1(AB)
R2(BCE)
R3(CD)
R4(AD)
```

This decomposition can be obtained with the so-called synthesis algorithm for 3NF, it is a lossless decomposition and preserves the Functional Dependencies.